# How to get the command sender from the Commands class to the DB class

Tags: java, minecraft

I have two classes of DB in which there is a method "GetMoney" and Commands

In general, the point is that in the DB class I need to somehow get a player, or rather the sender of the command that is written in the Commands class. How can I do this?

//DB - GETMONEY

```
    public int GetMoney(String name) throws Exception {
        String tableName = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("tableName");
        String dbNames = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("columnFirst");
        String dbBalance = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("columnSecond");
        Connection c = this.getConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet  res = s.executeQuery("SELECT " + dbBalance +" FROM "+ tableName +" WHERE " + dbNames +" = '"+ name +"'" );
        res.next();
        return res.getInt(dbBalance);   
    }
```

//COMMANDS - onCommand

```
 @Override
    public  boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        
        
        String name = sender.getName();;

        if(args.length == 0 ) {
            
            String showBalance = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("messages.showBalance"); 
            
            
            try {
                int balance = this.database.GetMoney(name);
                showBalance = showBalance.replace("&", "\u00a7").replace("_nm", name).replace("_bl", String.valueOf(balance));
                sender.sendMessage(showBalance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just pass it as an argument like you do with `name`?

Comment: I tried to pass Player instead but as always it return null, and i nedd sender of command, which prescribed in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I think passing Player interface is better than a simple name. First you have to make sure the sender is a Player not a ConsoleCommandSender. After this you can pass the Player and in the GetMoney() method you simply get the player's name with player.getName() method.

EDIT: I saw you need the command sender. You can pass it too instead of player just replace GetMoney parameter with CommandSender and delete instance check where we determine the sender is a player or not. After all you simply check it again wherever you want and cast it to Player again.

```
@Override
    public  boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                Player player = (Player) sender;

                String showBalance = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("messages.showBalance");
                try {
                    int balance = this.database.GetMoney(player);
                    showBalance = showBalance.replace("&", "\u00a7").replace("_nm", player.getName()).replace("_bl", String.valueOf(balance));
                    sender.sendMessage(showBalance);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                sender.sendMessage("Player only command.");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
//DB - Getmoney
    public int GetMoney(Player player) throws Exception {
        String tableName = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("tableName");
        String dbNames = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("columnFirst");
        String dbBalance = this.plugin.getConfig().getString("columnSecond");
        
        Connection c = this.getConnection();
        Statement s = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet  res = s.executeQuery("SELECT " + dbBalance +" FROM "+ tableName +" WHERE " + dbNames +" = '"+ player.getName() +"'" );
        res.next();
        return res.getInt(dbBalance);
    }
```